# Is there a way to cache data coming from redux connect in React function component with using useRef()?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

The way I cache data in Class component is like below :
1. make async API call in componentDidMount
2. get API response and dispatch data through redux
3. use response data by mapping state to prop

What I want to do is caching data right after you get API response with mapped redux state value
inside of `useEffect` in function component
(
It works on class component. but I'm wondering how should I make it work in function component)

```js
export class MyClassComponent extends React.Component {
    private readonly _myCachedData = {
         'data1': {}
    }

    public async componentDidMount() {
        await this.loadAsyncData();
    }

    private loadAsyncData() {
        const { makeAPICall } = this.props
        await makeAPICall();
        return this._myCachedData.data1 = this.props.data1FromReduxConnect;
    }
}

export const mapStateTopProps = (state) => {
    const { data1FromReduxConnect } = state;
    return data1FromReduxConnect;
}
...
```

What I have tried :

```js
export const MyFunctionComponent = props => {
    const { data1FromReduxConnect } = props;
    const myCachedData = React.useRef();
    const loadAsyncData = () => {
        const { makeAPICall } = this.props
        await makeAPICall();
        return myCachedData.current = data1FromReduxConnect;
    }
    React.useEffect(()=> {
        await loadAsyncData();
    })

}

export const mapStateTopProps = (state) => {
    const { data1FromReduxConnect } = state;
    return data1FromReduxConnect;
}
```

I was only able to get the previous value of`data1FromReduxConnect` unlike class component did get updated value `this.props.data1FromReduxConnect` after API call

Not sure if I should just keep class component for it, or is there a way to deal with this issue!
Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you need to cache the data if it's already in the store?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is the right way to use the [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook. Similar to React's class components' `createRef()`, it is actually used to access the DOM in functional components.

If the HTTP request happens only once when `MyFunctionComponent` is initialised, we can use `[]` as the second argument in the `useEffect` hook which will cause this effect to be [run only once](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects). In addition, we will need to make use of [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) hook to keep track of the component's state which is to be updated with the values from the redux store.

```
export const MyFunctionComponent = props => {
    const { data1FromReduxConnect } = props;
    const [ myData, setMyData ] = useState();

    const loadAsyncData = async() => {
        const { makeAPICall } = this.props
        await makeAPICall();
    }

    useEffect(()=> {
      async function getData() {
        await loadAsyncData();
      }
      getData();
      // do the rest to get and store data from redux
      setMyData(data1FromReduxConnect);
    }, [])

}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer.
But react doc tells us that it can be used in function component  similar way you’d use instance fields in classes.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: @tlrmacl yes, agree, but what you aren't exactly trying to access to DOM instance in this case, right?